# Find distance between two Android devices using GPS

Tags: android, gps

is it possible that I can get the coordinates of another phone when that phone has no WIFI on? I want to calculate the distance between two phones but none of the phones is connected on wifi. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

you can get distance
**between two latitude and Longitude**
 So if you are able to get latitude and longitude between two device then you can get the distance using following code

```
public static float calculateDistance(float lat1, float lon1, float lat2, float lon2)
    {
        float dLat = (float) Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        float dLon = (float) Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        float a =
                (float) (Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                        * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2));
        float c = (float) (2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a)));
        float d = earthRadius * c;
        return d;
    }
```

Comment: so can I get the longitude and latitude of phone2 on phone1 without them having a wifi connection?

Comment: you must access a network task (any web service) to get the geolocation of another device.